# php simplexml set attribute

Tags: php, xml

the simple example xml file is

```
<body id="1" doi="100000">
</body>
```

php

```
  $feed = file_get_contents('/../files/schema.xml');
  $datasetxml = simplexml_load_string($feed);
  $datasetxml->body['id']=2;
  $datasetxml->body['doi']="200000";
  echo $datasetxml->asXML();
```

I want to change it as id=2 and doi=200000 but after reset value the result is wrong and only can see in the web page source?

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <body id="1" doi="100000">

 <body id="2" doi="200000"/></body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's the root element you want to change, try directly working on it:

```
$datasetxml = simplexml_load_string('<body id="1" doi="100000">
</body>');
$datasetxml['id']=2;
$datasetxml['doi']="200000";
echo $datasetxml->asXML();
```

Because `$datasetxml` is already the element it's attributes you want to change.

Answer (score 1):

```
$feed = file_get_contents('/../files/schema.xml');
$datasetxml = simplexml_load_string($feed);
$datasetxml->body[0]['id']=2;
$datasetxml->body[0]['doi']="200000";
echo $datasetxml->asXML();
```

Comment: This works if you add a root entity to your xml. It seems you can't modify root attribute.